# Android Select from attached database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an Android application where I have attached a database to my current database connection, but when I try to select from a table from the attached database I get an error reporting that there is no such table.

```
SQLiteDatabase dbc;
try {
    dbc = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_RECOVERY,Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    dbc.execSQL(TABLE_COMPLETE);
    dbc.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + DBRECOVERY_FULL_PATH + "' as MasterDb;");
    dbc.execSQL("SELECT * FROM MasterDb.properties;");
    db.close();
    dbc.close();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SQLException: " + e.toString(), 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have also tried:

```
dbc.execSQL("SELECT 'MasterDb', * FROM MasterDb.properties;");
```

But each time, it is reporting that there is no such table.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `query` method from `SQLiteDatabase` can simplify your work, but according to your query try using `dbc.execSQL("SELECT * FROM MasterDb");`

Comment: Selecting from MasterDb isn't specifing any table that is just the database i need to get data from the properties table in the MasterDb.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that to use an "attached" database you need to open it with this flag:

```
SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS
```

See *[SQLiteDatabase OpenDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29)*.

To open the database you will need to run something like this:

```
String path = getDatabasePath("YourDbName").getAbsolutePath();
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY + SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Comment: How do I open a database with that flag?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I forgot to copy the new DB to the file path before attaching it.